# Assigning url from XML file to string does not escape?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have a snippet of XML that looks like this:

```
<url>
\\network\folder
<url>
```

When I read this into a string using `string url = XElement("url").Value`, the value that is stored in the string variable is:

`\\\\network\\folder`

How can I return it as a verbatim url?

Comment: That is the escaped string.  '\' requires a '\' before it to actually be valid.  You are looking at in the Watch.  If you do a Console.WriteLine(url) or Debug.WriteLine(url), you should see that it will come out just like it went in.

Comment: No it is not `\\\\network\\folder`, you just see it so  in VS debugger. See it in `Text Visualizer`

Comment: Is it really stored like that? Or is that only what you see in the debugger? Try `Console.WriteLine(url);` and I'm sure you'll see what you expect.

Comment: This is likely dup - aren't you looking at the value in debug output? Check each character individually to prove yourself that there is correct number of slashes.

Comment: @iMortalitySX - Ah you are correct,  it was confusing me.

Comment: I ran into the same issue one time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing this during debug mode (in a watch windows for example), it's ok : the "\\" is used in C# to represent a "\". The same way a "\t" is tab and the "\n" is carriage return.

Look at [the whole list of single-escape-sequences](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/9.4.4.4.htm).

Comment: Thanks, This was confusing the hell out of me.  I wrote it to the Console line and in fact saw that it was correct, but stepping through the debugger shows \\\\ for example